# Django MPTT - how expensive is objects.rebuild?

Tags: django, performance, django-mptt

I will roll out in the next days an application which is using Django MPTT to manage hierarchical data. MPTT provides a function called [rebuild](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/managers.py#L434), which rebuilds all trees available for a given model, and is called as such `TreeNodes.objects.rebuild()`. As you can see the command is called on the model, not on an instance of the model. This command has to be called after a node has been inserted into a tree.

For Django MPTT 0.6 (not yet officially [released](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/250)) a [partial_rebuild](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/managers.py#L457) command is implemented, which will only rebuild the given tree.

While testing locally with up to 10 trees it is no performance issue at all, but I'm concerned when there are 100s of trees in my db, and I'm calling the `rebuild` command (which will rebuild all 100s of trees), this might be a significant performance issue.

Anybody out there who has experience with using the `rebuild` command?

Comment: Any reason you would rebuild your trees on a regular basis?

Comment: As far as I understand Django-mptt one always have to rebuild the tree after adding a node to the tree like so: node.parent = parent , node.save() , which has to follow a TreeNodes.objects.rebuild() command.

Comment: Have you tested the results of your operations without any subsequent rebuilds? I dare to say, that this is not necessary at all. Have a look at the TreeManager implementation.

Comment: Yes you are probably right. I think I experience an issue with how mptt is setting the left right values of the node. They are fine if I always add the node at the end of the childs, but set wrong if I add a node at the beginning of the childs. It seems as, for the last case, my order_insertion_by meta setting is ignored. Interestingly, a rebuild fixes the left right values. Anyhow I will run some more tests and will let you know whats the outcome is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference..

objects.rebuild() is only needed in some special cases. Normally mptt sets the left and right values of your nodes correctly just by setting the parent id of your node. This is also mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/commit/8bbf286868957366504d08d0aab1e47a795abd89)

I experienced an issue with not correctly set left, right values because I saved the new node, !before! I reset the position values of the other, already existing siblings. When inserting new nodes for a tree with the meta attribute `order_insertion_by` set, one has to first reset the order_insertion_by value for all siblings, and after that, save the new node. This way mptt is able to recalculate correctly the left right values.

See my (simplified) example below:

models.py

```
class Node(MPTTModel):
    """
    Representation of a single node
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_children')
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=10) #for nodes on the same hierarchy level we have to define the position in which they are displayed 

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['position']
```

views.py

```
new_node = Node(name="new node", parent=parent_node, position=1)
update_node_positions(new_node, 1) #routine to update the node positions
new_node.save()
```

update_node_positions

```
def update_node_positions(node, mode):
    """
    Procedure to update the node positions
    Three different modes available:
        1 = insert node
        2 = update position, parent stays the same
        3 = update position and change parent
        4 = trashed
    """

    if mode == 1 or mode==3:
        #if node has been inserted at the beginning
        if node.position == 1:
            node.get_siblings().update(position=F('position') + 1)
        #if node has been inserted not at beginning and not at the last position
        elif node.position != node.get_siblings().count() + 1:
            #update positions of siblings right of node by one
            node.get_siblings().filter(position__gte=node.position).update(position=F('position') + 1)
        if mode == 3:
            #since we removed the node from a parent, we have to decrement the positions of the former siblings right of the node by one
            if node._original_parent is not None:
                #do updates only for nodes which had a parent before. will not be executed for root nodes
                node._original_parent.get_children().filter(position__gt=node._original_position).update(position=F('position') - 1)
    if mode == 2:
        #if old position is left of new position -> decrement position by 1 for nodes which have position <= node.position AND > node.original_position
        if node.position > node._original_position:
            node.get_siblings().filter(Q(position__lte=node.position) & Q(position__gt=node._original_position)).update(position=F('position') - 1)
        #if old position is right of new position -> increment position by 1 for nodes which have position >= node.position AND < node.original_position 
        if node.position < node._original_position:
            node.get_siblings().filter(Q(position__gte=node.position) & Q(position__lt=node._original_position)).update(position=F('position') + 1)
    if mode == 4:
        #decrement position by 1 for nodes which have position > node.position
        node.get_siblings().filter(Q(position__gt=node.position)).update(position=F('position') - 1)
```